# How to find significant attributes from two different data sets

Tags: r, statistics

I have 2 data sets, a collection of attributes for entity A and a collection of attributes for entity B. For simplicity, assume entity A is a User and entity B is a restaurant bill. Attributes of entity A could be Name, Age, Country, State, City, etc. and that of bill could be restaurant Name, Country, State, City, Food item, etc. What statistical model can be used to evaluate the food habits. ie. there are larger number of occurrences when the Country or State or City or anything else matches between both sets. In other words, which attribute match has a higher significance. How can we find this in R?

**Sample Collection:**

```
collection1 = [
    {UserId:x, Country:US, State:New York, City: New York},
    {UserId:y, Country:US, State:Florida, City:Orlando},
    {UserId:z, Country:US, State:Florida, City:FortMyers}
]

collection2 = [
    {UserId:x, RestaurantName:a, Country:US, State:New York, City: New York},
    {UserId:y, RestaurantName:b, Country:US, State:Florida, City:Orlando}
    {UserId:z, RestaurantName:c, Country:Canada, State:Ontario, City:Toronto}
]
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `var()` and `cov()`. But since you posted no code it is hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I haven't started coding as I am not clear on the model. The code would just create these 2 collections.

collection1 = []

Comment: You will get much better answers here if you post code. This forum is not really for Q&A, but for "why is this not working right?" kind of questions.

Comment: If you are asking about statistical models, you should ask at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead. This site is for specific programming questions.